# Rate limiting load balanced environment using a distributed cache

Tags: caching, redis, hazelcast, distributed

My question is about a fundamental functionality of the distributed cache, my use case is a rate limiter implementation on a load balanced environment, each request from the same endpoint should increment a request-counter for that endpoint, I'm trying to understand how a distributed cache works in this situation when each request is directed to a different (load balanced) cluster node, is the endpoint request-count stored on a single node of the cluster? in this case the network load is inefficient, isn't it?, can I configure the cluster to replicate the data for reads? wouldn't this cause consistency issues and write penalties on the cache cluster when increment is preformed on the counter? Do distributed caches use any quorum based mechanisms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental question regarding distributed systems. It is covered basically under CAP Theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

C = Consistent, A = Available, P = Partitioned (distributed)

You can only have 2 of the 3 - you have to make trade offs according to your use case.

My experience is with Hazelcast ([www.hazelcast.org](http://www.hazelcast.org)) which by default is an AP system using a data partitioning scheme. Hazelcast also has a CP subsystem to offer guaranteed consistency over availability.

https://hazelcast.com/blog/riding-the-cp-subsystem/

Coincidentally I advised a bit on a rate limiting system using Hazelcast a year or so ago. It did precisely what your talking about. You just have to take the pieces and architect a system that meets your neeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Cluster quorum, replicated maps - they are all there in Hazelcast but if I understood your requirement correctly, you do not need any of them. I think what you are asking for can have a very simple answer:

- Use a distributed map
- Assign a unique identifier to each endpoint and use this identifier as "key" when a request is generated from that endpoint.
- As for the value, you have various options to keep the count. For example - a simple AtomicInteger (Java SDK's, not Hazelcast IAtomicInteger).

Comment: Yes but in this case the value of the count will be stored on a single (master)partition of the cluster and on some slave partitions for backup as well. So every incrementation will "travel" the network to retreive and update the value from the master parition. For a distributed system with potentially thousands of calls per second, would't it eventually cause a call flood and failure of the distributed cahce network, i mean is it correct use of the cache?

Comment: For purely caching purposes, it is normal for a few million calls moving through the cluster at any give time. For very complex business operations which entails executing complex algorithms etc on Hazelcast servers, 100s of 1000s of such operations per second is trivial. If you are using distributed systems then worrying about where your data is stored goes against the principles of using a distributed system in the first place. The focus should rather be on accessing data and within expected/required SLAs.